# What are the limitations of the Matlab fileread command in -nodesktop mode?

Tags: matlab, file-io

Assuming a text file with 7718 characters (e.g. the contents cut and pasted from [here](http://chem.tufts.edu/answersinscience/relativityofwrong.htm))

The command `fileread('myfile.txt')` fails when I launch matlab with `matlab -nodesktop` but works in desktop mode.

Does anyone have any idea why?

If the number of characters in the text file is reduced to 1981 it works in `-nodesktop` mode.

*Note*:I do not know the exact number of characters at which it stops working.

Finally, I am using Matlab 7.8.0 (R2009a) on Windows7.

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of Matlab?

Comment: No. I will do if I get a chance though.

Comment: Do you get any error message when it fails?

Comment: No, it freezes and I get a windows dialog box saying 'MATLAB has stopped working'.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this odd behaviour (Matlab 2010b & 2012b, both on Linux).

You could at least try to "debug" this type of behaviour by restricting the problem. The "fileread" routine does some checks on the file name (ischar, isempty), then opens the file (fopen), reads it (fread) and closes it (fclose) - rather simple basic stuff. For reference, type "edit fileread" into the command line of the matlab desktop and try running down the routine step by step.

If "fread" causes the whole thing to crash and if you're bound to this version of Matlab, try implementing a "fix". "fread" accepts a few more parameters than what is used in "fileread" (the file ID and the precision "char" only): FREAD(FID,SIZE,PRECISION,SKIP,MACHINEFORMAT). Specifying more parameters may help (wild guess but worth a try).