# Is there a recommended way to repeatedly call matlab from an external program?

Tags: windows, matlab, batch-file, erlang

I am repeatedly calling a matlab script `MyMatlabScript` from another program (written in Erlang). I am doing this using a batch file containing the following:

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -wait -r "addpath('C:/...'); MyMatlabScript; %quit;"
```

This means that Matlab has to launch everytime I run the batch file script. It works but is slow*.

To improve performance I would like to be able to launch Matlab once and then somehow, using Erlang or a batch script, repeatedly initiate my Matlab script using that one instance of Matlab.

Can this be done?

Note, I am using Matlab 7.8.0 (R2009a) on Windows7.

*Extra slow due to issue outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233921/what-are-the-limitations-of-the-matlab-fileread-command-in-nodesktop-mode)!

Comment: If it is the same script/set of scripts you need to run from outside matlab, you may consider compiling them as stand alone application using mex compiler in matlab - which would allow running them without cose of starting matlab, and may potentioally solve the problem you outlined in other question...

Comment: `mex` allows you to compile C or Fortran code to be called from MATLAB, not to compile MATLAB to a standalone form to be called from other environments. MATLAB Compiler, a separate add-on product, does this. However the standalone components can take nearly as long to start as MATLAB itself, as they run against a MATLAB Compiler Runtime. The right approach here is to call MATLAB as a COM automation server as @Navan suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know whether passing messages into Matlab is a viable option, but I would like to propose an alternative. Matlab has a "timer" object, which lets you specify a call-back-function. In regular intervals, the Matlab call-back-function could check a file, which is changed by your Erlang program. A changed file triggers the desired Matlab routine. Well, it is not "haute cuisine" in terms of programming style, but it should do the job.

Answer (score 6):

It is not simple. But you can try using COM automation server interface in MATLAB. You need to have Erlang library for interfacing with COM automation servers. With this interface you can create an automation server and then keep sending commands to it. The documentation is available at http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-matlab-com-automation-server.html. In the documentation there are examples which use Visual Basic code.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience in just this.  There are three predominant options:

1. Erlang command line calls to Matlab using os:cmd()
2. Writing a protocol that will require the two applications to be separate and communicate over tcpip.  Benefit is the now Erlang is a server or vice-versa, however you code it.  Challenge is the protocol code in Matlab, Erlang is particularly built for it.
3. Make a system pipe.  If you're sticking to windows (NamedSystemPipe) then you really shouldn't have a problem finding docs around on how to do it.

I prefer Method 3 for local only comm and 2 for anything network based.  Using 1 gives you the absolute least flexibility.  There are more but since you're asking, this is what I recommend.

And best of all is that 'slow' problem is gone by not using 1.